# how to redirect subdomain to root domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect this subdomain:

`https://forum.example.com/forums/CDB/general` 
will goes to --->
 `https://example.com/`

Currently ONLY when someone tries to go to `https://forum.example.com`
I redirect him with CNAME to `https://example.com/` but If they go to the `/forums/*` I'm getting a 404 error.
I want all `https://domain/forums/*` to go to `https://example.com`

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/ [R=301]
```